# How to I add a button using content script in dailymotion video

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am making a dailymotion video download I need help from the community regarding one things that how can access the page url and append it like this `https://savethevideo.net/#url=dailymotionlink`.

Also, how can I put this link into a button on any dailymotion video.
[this is the image explaining where exactly i want the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkodt.png)

Now, for clarity I telling you in points what i need.

1. How do I make link link the above.
2. How do I add the link I have made into the dailymotion video as a download button.

Comment: Do you have access to dailymotion website and code ? Please add some code here or otherwise read this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its like youtube all pages are same. Just go to dailymotion and click on any video you want and just see its page source code. that is code in which i have to insert it.